# Telerik Scheduler Drag&Drop

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, telerik, draggable, scheduler

iam currently working on a big project.
Now iam stuck, where i must transfer a resource from Scheduler1 as an appointment from Scheduler2.
Both schedulers are in the TimeLineView.

Is it possible to Drag a resource (from Scheduler1) on Scheduler2 to create an new appointment?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this demo will help get you started: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/draganddropintegration/defaultcs.aspx?product=scheduler

Maybe the OnClientAppointmentMoveEnd event will fire if you drag appointments so you may be able to get that they were dropped over the other scheduler. Or just try to listen for the standard browser drop event on the second scheduler and debug what elements you get to discern appointments (e.g., by their class).

In either case you would then need to initiate a data source update like in the demo I linked

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I will take a look, but iam not sure, that it works, because i dont want to drag and drop an appointment. But thanks, i will check this

Comment: I don't have enough experience with the scheduler control to be more specific, but I hope these ideas will help you. If you succeed, post your solution in this thread and/or in a Telerik code library (you will even earn points for the latter), as it may be interesting to other people.

Comment: Currently we solved our problem temporary without drag&drop. But if i find a way, i will post it :)